# How to enable JavaScript IntelliSense for custom file extensions in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, file-extension

The question title says it all. My organization uses a non-standard file extension on source code written using JavaScript. Changing the file extension to ".js" seems to activate IntelliSense.

However, I was wondering if the IntelliSense could be activated using the non-standard file extension.

Answer (score 5):

Click the bottom right of the window where it says "Plain Text" or the name of the detected language.  This will bring up a menu at the top that lets you change it for the current session and also configure that specific extension to always be interpreted as JS.
[image: VS Code Bottom Toolbar]
[image: VS Code Language selection Menu]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `files.associations` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.customExtension": "javascript"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15416) (found in a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+nonstandard+file+extension)), it sounds like the TypeScript language service does not support non-standard extensions, so you won't be able to get semantic features like type-based completions (which I assumed was what you meant by IntelliSense).  The techniques described in the other answers may give you basic syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Those who needs this functionality for a plugin can use the following contribution in their `package.json` files:

```json
"contributes": {
  "languages": [
    {
      "id": "javascript",
      "extensions": [
        ".myext"
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

This defines a file extension call `myext` that will be treated as javascript which comes very handy for adding intellisense to virtual files.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.languages
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-documents